# smtpDataError(550)for sending email

Tags: python, email, python-requests, host, smtplib

```py
import os
import smtplib, ssl


def send_mail(msg) :
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465

    user_mail = "pradeepacharya626@gmail.com"
    password = os.getenv("News_Pass")

    receiver = "pradeepacharya626@gmail.com"
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=host,port=port,context=context) as server:
        server.login(user_mail,password)
        server.sendmail(user_mail,receiver,msg)
```

I want to send email using python code, but I get the following error: smtpDataError(550).
What should I do?

Comment: The 550 error from Gmail means your name is currently on a blacklist because you sent too many messages in one day, or the recipient has specifically blocked you.